# Cannot send github actions to a specific branch 'staging'

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions

I've created a master.yml and staging.yml to send deploy my backend php with ftp deploy but isn't scheduling the job on github actions.
This is my staging.yml

````
on:
  push:
    branches: [staging]
name: Staging 
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name:  Sync files
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.2
        with:
          server: ${{ secrets.ftp_host }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
          server-dir: staging/backend/
    ```
````

Comment: What do you mean by _"isn't scheduling the job on github actions"_ ? Could you be more specific?

Comment: when i push to master adds the job: [IMG 1](https://imgur.com/byWcURL) 
when i push to staging nothing happens: [IMG 2](https://imgur.com/yHL11td)

Comment: Is the `staging` workflow also present on the default repo branch? Or only on the staging branch?

Comment: is present on both

Comment: The workflow implementation is correct. I've got something quite similar [in this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/39-extract-from-branch.yml) which always triggered [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/workflows/39-extract-from-branch.yml) when pushing to the expected branch. Is the workflow implementation the same on both branches (master and staging)?